# Sapper/svelte - integrate old js library that references 'window' and 'document'

Tags: svelte, legacy-code, sapper

I'm really enjoying working with Svelte and Sapper.

I have created apps using the standard sapper "rollup" configuration.

I'd like to create a sapper/svelte app including the ancient OpenLayers library from 2013. OpenLayers.min.js is a  `var OpenLayers = { ... };` js library. It also references 'window' and 'document' within this.

I've tried various approaches without success:

1. Adding `export default OpenLayers;` to the end of OpenLayers.min.js file. Here, sapper objects to the library referencing 'window' and 'document'.
2. Attempting to use `@rollup/plugin-legacy`
3. Attempting to get catch a load event when OpenLayers.min.js loads as a script in `onMount(async () => ...` function

Does anyone know of a way I can use this venerable library?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the more recent version of the package that supports ES6 modules? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol

Comment: Many reasons; mainly that I have a large body of bespoke code that uses OL2